# Use context.xml outside web application

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource, jndi

I have a web application deployed under Tomcat, with some configuration defined in its **context.xml** such as an Oracle datasource. (the **context.xml** is either in the webapp directory or in the Tomcat configuration directory according to what we choose).

The thing is, I want to use the datasource defined in the **context.xml** of the web application inside a service/daemon that runs alongside (not under Tomcat then), and I would like to use it as simply as in the code below:

```
    DataSource      vDs;
    //--------------------------------
    // Initialize the database connection using the JNDI DataSource :
    // jdbc/oracleds
    //--------------------------------                   
    try
        {
        InitialContext  vInitContext    = new InitialContext();
        vDs             = ( DataSource ) vInitContext.lookup( Const.kJNDIDataSourceView );  
        }
    catch( NamingException vE )
        {
        LogManager.logException( vE, "", 0, true );
        throw new RuntimeException();
        }
```

The thing is, I could not find how to give a path to my **context.xml** in the JNDI API.
I could of course manually parse it and configure my connection, but I would like to spare the effort.

Comment: Does your tomcat support jndi and DataSource ? How does it expect to e configured?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen Yes, I have no problem to use the datasource from my Tomcat web application. What I am trying to achieve is using the same context.xml from a Java program that does not run under Tomcat. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Then you need something else to provide the jndi stuff. If you fully control all the code I would suggest using dependency injection instead.